# What's Java's equivalent of asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: c#, java, .net, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

Giving the similarity between C# and Java, I expect Java having similar programming support. I heard Java has this Future stuff but I don't know similar it is to C# asynchronous patterns.

Comment: Related [Futures and Callables](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures). I recommend to read the whole article to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Java basics suggest that for asynchronous processing you have to start a different thread (new or reused). So the simplest code would be as follows:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()) {
    public void run() {
        // your asynchronous code.
    }
});
t.start();
```

In later versions of java plenty new features were introduced, but they are all based on this simple construct.

For instance, `Future` and `FutureTask` mentioned before help facilitate catching result of method invocation performed in a parallel thread. There are many more features in the latest versions of java and particularly in package `java.util.concurrent`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: You can also store the anonymous `Runnable`s in an accumulated list, then run all of them within the original thread (if there's an event loop/or persistent thread) or in a new thread all at once at some future moment.  I believe that is what the `Executor` utility class does for you.